# Getting control 1's position in a group with only 1 controls when doing repaint (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity3d, многопоточность, gui

Стал сталкиваться с такой вот ошибкой:

```
ArgumentException: Getting control 1's position in a group with only 1 controls when doing repaint
    Aborting
```

Это не критично но хотелось бы,её убрать. Она возникает из-за:

> OnGUI вызывается несколько раз за кадр, и если вы рисуете разное
>   количество элементов управления в одном из тех, которые вызываются в
>   одном и том же кадре, вы можете получить это сообщение об ошибке.

[Тут](https://forum.unity.com/threads/argumentexception-getting-control-0s-position-in-a-group-with-only-0-controls-when.135021/?_ga=2.54233768.1005089624.1576656734-315785957.1570008228) я нашёл это пояснение. Но не понял как это пофиксить.

Мой код :

```
   Rect FooterSection;
   void OnGUI()
    {
        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
        string[] tabs = { "Объекты", "Назначение/Просмотр DATA у Terrain", "Настройки" };
        // selectedTab = GUILayout.Toolbar(selectedTab, tabs, tabStyle);
        selectedTab = GUILayout.Toolbar(selectedTab, tabs);
        switch (selectedTab)
        {
            case 0:
                DrawLayouts();
                DrawHeader();
                DrawLeft();
                DrawRight(true);
                DrawFooter();
                break;
            case 1:
                DrawListTerrain();
                break;
            case 2:
                DrawTabSettings();
                break;
        }
        EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck();
    }
    void DrawTabSettings()
    {
        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
        string[] tabsSettings = { "Общие настройки", "Добавление/Удаление объекта" };
        selectedTabSettings = GUILayout.Toolbar(selectedTabSettings, tabsSettings);
        switch (selectedTabSettings)
        {
            case 0:
                DrawSettings();
                break;
            case 1:
                DrawAddDeleteObj();
                break;
        }
        EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck();
    }
    void OnEnable()
    {
        ...
        InitTextures();
        ...
    }
    void DrawSettings()
    {
        moduleSettings settTerr = new moduleSettings();
        if (GUILayout.Button("Удалить размещённые деревья"))
        {
            settTerr.DeletTrees();
        }
        if (GUILayout.Button("TreeDistance=12000"))
        {
            settTerr.TreeDistance();
        }
        if (GUILayout.Button("TerrainTexturing"))//ошибка
        {
            // settTerr.TerrainTexturing();
            _thread = new Thread(() => settTerr.TerrainTexturing()); //ошибка
            _progress = 0;
            _thread.Start();
            pressedbool = true;
        }
        if (pressedbool)//ошибка
        {
            drawProgressBarOnGUI(FooterSection, 4);
            Dispatcher.Instance.InvokePending();
        }
        if (GUILayout.Button("Вывести в консоль количество деревьев на Terrain"))
        {
            settTerr.Showtreesname();
        }



        tempPrefab = (UnityEngine.Object)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Prefab для редакитования объектов:", tempPrefab, typeof(UnityEngine.Object), true);

        if (tempPrefab != null)
        {
            EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
            prefabEditingBool = EditorGUILayout.ToggleLeft("Вкл./выкл. режим редактирования объектов.", prefabEditingBool);
            if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
            {
                string stringtoggle = "UPDATE Setting SET EditModeBool=" + prefabEditingBool + " ";
                Debug.Log(stringtoggle);
                ObjectDataBase.UpdateSELECTObj(stringtoggle);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            prefabEditingBool = false;
        }


        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        stringObjfileURL = GUILayout.TextField(stringObjfileURL);
        if (GUILayout.Button("Обзор..."))
        {
            stringObjfileURL = EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel("All obj files", "", "obj");
            // objtojsonConvert();
            // trimLink();
        }
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical();
        mapoffsetx = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("map offset x:", mapoffsetx);
        mapoffsetz = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("map offset z:", mapoffsetz);
        EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();

        if (GUILayout.Button("Сохранить настройки"))
        {
            string path = "";
            if (tempPrefab != null)
            {
                path = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(tempPrefab);
            }
            else
            {
                path = "";
            }
            string stringtoggle;
            if (path != "")
            {
                stringtoggle = "UPDATE Setting SET EditModeBool=" + prefabEditingBool + ", PrefabForEditing='" + path + "', mapoffsetx='" + (double)mapoffsetx + "', mapoffsetz='" + (double)mapoffsetz + "', ObjfileURL = '" + stringObjfileURL + "' ";
            }
            else
            {
                stringtoggle = "UPDATE Setting SET EditModeBool=" + prefabEditingBool + ", PrefabForEditing='yesnull', mapoffsetx='" + (double)mapoffsetx + "', mapoffsetz='" + (double)mapoffsetz + "', ObjfileURL = '" + stringObjfileURL + "' ";
            }
            Debug.Log(stringtoggle);
            ObjectDataBase.UpdateSELECTObj(stringtoggle);
        }
    }
    void InitTextures()
    {
        HeaderSectionTexture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
        HeaderSectionTexture.SetPixel(0, 0, HeaderSectionColor);
        HeaderSectionTexture.Apply();

        LeftSectionTexture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
        LeftSectionTexture.SetPixel(0, 0, LeftSectionColor);
        LeftSectionTexture.Apply();

        RightSectionTexture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
        RightSectionTexture.SetPixel(0, 0, RightSectionColor);
        RightSectionTexture.Apply();

        FooterSectionTexture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
        FooterSectionTexture.SetPixel(0, 0, FooterSectionColor);
        FooterSectionTexture.Apply();
    }
    void DrawLayouts()
    {
        HeaderSection.x = 0;
        HeaderSection.y = 20f;
        HeaderSection.width = Screen.width;
        HeaderSection.height = Screen.height / 7f - 20f;

        LeftSection.x = 0;
        LeftSection.y = Screen.height / 7f + 20f;
        LeftSection.width = Screen.width / 2f;
        LeftSection.height = Screen.height * 5f / 7f - 15f;

        RightSection.x = Screen.width / 2f;
        RightSection.y = Screen.height / 7f + 20f;
        RightSection.width = Screen.width / 2f;
        RightSection.height = Screen.height * 5f / 7f - 15f;

        FooterSection.x = 0;
        FooterSection.y = (Screen.height * 6f) / 7f;
        FooterSection.width = Screen.width;
        FooterSection.height = Screen.height / 7f + 15f;

        DeleteSection.x = 0;
        DeleteSection.y = Screen.height / 7f + 20f;
        DeleteSection.width = Screen.width;
        DeleteSection.height = Screen.height * 5f / 7f - 15f;

        GUI.DrawTexture(HeaderSection, HeaderSectionTexture);
        GUI.DrawTexture(LeftSection, LeftSectionTexture);
        GUI.DrawTexture(RightSection, RightSectionTexture);
        GUI.DrawTexture(FooterSection, FooterSectionTexture);
    }

public void drawProgressBarOnGUI(Rect widthRect, int y = 1)
{
    EditorGUI.ProgressBar(new Rect(0, (widthRect.height / 2) * y, widthRect.width, 20), _progress / 100.0f, "progress: " + _progress + "%");
}
```

Что надо написать в условиях или как выполнить задачу в отдельном потоке, чтоб этого не возникало?

Comment: В цитате написан бред. OnGUI работает не так.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker А как ? Я мог ошибиться с переводом, но в обсуждении написано так.

Comment: Приведите код drawProgressBarGUI

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Опубликовал в вопросе

Comment: Окей, предоставьте код, который создает `FooterSection`.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Дополнил ответ , написал как создаётся FooterSection.

Comment: Не, тут без всего кода тогда проблему не найти) Я могу написать общий ответ, как фиксить эту проблему, а вы уже сами найдете, там в принципе не очень сложно, сойдет?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102436/discussion-between-ivan-triumphov-and-riotbr3aker).

Comment: Остались какие-то вопросы?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker   Да остались . Я пока только прочитал . В понедельник буду на работе . Там уточню если что . Хорошо?

Comment: Разумеется, я просто подумал, что совсем все непонятно из ответа, вот и уточнил :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[В IMGUI есть много событий](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventType.html), но все они вы вызываются после события `Layout`, например:

```
Layout -> Repaint
Layout -> MouseDown  
Layout -> ScrollWheel
```

Важно в здесь именно то, что события всегда происходят попарно и каждому событию **всегда** предшествует `Layout`.

При всем этом ничто не мешает написать такой код:

```
if(Event.current.type == EventType.Repaint){
    EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Label");
}
```

И такой, к примеру, код как раз вызовет ошибку:

> Getting control 0's position in a group with only 0 controls when
>   doing repaint

---

Почему это и как оно произошло?

На этапе `Layout` регистрируются **все** `Rect` будущих элементов, совершенно не важно, где они находятся и какого они размера. Этот этап нужен именно для регистрации вхождений элементов в верстку.

На этапе `Repaint` в примере выше мы пытаемся написать строку через автоматическую верстку, предварительно не зарегистрировав его на этапе `Layout`. От чего в псевдо-массиве верстки *в данном случае* 0 вхождений, а строка в `if` пытается получить *следующий*, т.е. вхождение с индексом 0 в массиве с размером 0.

---

Как это исправить?

Без полного кода не понять, но скорее всего есть какой-то `if`, который что-то внутри себя рисует в окне. Лучше менять все меняющие GUI переменные внутри события `Repaint` в конце метода `OnGUI`, **либо** делать все то же самое в самом начале метода `OnGUI` внутри события `Layout`. Возможно, это не самое элегантное решение, но такое изменение гарантирует, что следующий или текущий `Layout` получит "свежие" данные для верстки. Да и по кастомным разработкам редактора очень мало статей и в целом примеров, так что это единственное, что лично я смог придумать.

---

### P.S.

"Внутри события" - это так:

```
if(Event.current.type == EventType.Repaint){}
```

Comment: Я обновил вопрос постарался  отразить всё что происходит в OnGUI() . У меня сложная система табов и отрисовки слоёв , всё рисуется не так однозначно, чтоб это можно было спокойно переставлять в начало, конец

Comment: У меня вообще стало возникать это, после того как я стал использовать потоки... ошибка помечена комментарием //ошибка

Comment: В условие добавил Event.current.type == EventType.Repaint. Вроде перестала возникать. Спасибо. Разобрался

Comment: @IvanTriumphov в этом и проблема IMGUI, благо уже начали все менять на новую xml-css систему, года через 2-3 о IMGUI и ее косяках можно будет забыть :)

Comment: @IvanTriumphov и прошу прощения, я неверно выразился. Изменение переменных нужно ставить не в самый конец `OnGUI`, а в конец логического блока кода, а вообще советую отрисовки разных частей GUI выносить в методы, где и удобно вызывать изменение данных в событиях.

Answer (score 0):

Может кому пригодится.
Ошибку можно вылечить, если пропустить отрисовку GUI при срабатывании if. Надо не сразу рисовать GUI, а запустить счетчик, и рисовать когда он дойдет до 2. Глазом незаметно. Не знаю как конкретно, но работает. :)

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае:

1. помог счетчик, апдейтю его в обычном `Update`, в `OnGUI` жду пока счетчик не поднимется до 0.1 сек, для глаза приемлемо
2. `OnGUI` срабатывает дважды за фрейм, так что лучше ждать не количество прошедших фреймов, а промежуток времени.

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае в Canvas была анимированная кнопка и анимированная строка. Выбивало ошибку ТС. Достаточно было ввести статичную панель, к ней дочкой привязать бегущую строку и ОШИБКА ПРОПАЛА )))

[image: Ошибка ТС]